# Python app send a get link to a server, get a 200 OK response, but the server script doesn't execute

Tags: php, python, mysql, python-2.7

I am trying to make a python app wich would insert data in a SQL database.
To achieve this I have made the python app send parameters in a GET request, and writed a php script which is supposed to get them and make the SQL request

The Python script is (shortened):

```
import httplib
import time

dd = time.time().__str__()[:-3]
d = time.time().__str__()[:-3]

link = str('?id_machine=1,type_erreur=ping,description_erreur=test,date_detection=' + dd + ',date=' + d)
print link

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('localhost')

conn.request('GET','/test/erreur.php' + link)
res = conn.getresponse()
print res.status
print res.reason
```

And when executed print:

```
drakasan@debian:~$ python Ingesup/Web/AgentS.py 
?id_machine=1,type_erreur=ping,description_erreur=test,date_detection=1381245779,date=1381245779
200
OK
```

And here is the php script:

```
<?php
    $page ='Ajoutsalle';
    require_once ('connect.php');

    $id_machine=htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['id_machine']));
    $type_machine=htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['type_machine']));
    $description_erreur=htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['description_erreur']));
    $date_detection=htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['date_detection']));
    $date=htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['date']));

    if($nom_machine && $id_salle && $ip && $systeme)
    {
        $query = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM erreur WHERE id='".$id."'");
        $rows=$query->rowCount();
        if($rows==1)
        {
            echo" <div id='error'>Ip existe deja </div>";
        } else {
            $req = $connect->prepare('INSERT INTO     erreur(id_machine,type_erreur,description_erreur,date_detection,date) VALUES(:id_machine,:type_erreur,:description_erreur,:date_detection,:date)');
            $req->execute(array(
                'id_machine'         => $id_machine,
                'type_machine'       => $type_machine,
                'description_erreur' => $description_erreur,
                'date_detection'     => $date_detection,
                'date'               => $date,
            ));
        }

    } else echo "vous devez renseigner tous les champs";
?>
<html>
    <form method='GET' action='#'>
    </form>
</html>
```

The "bliss" database is as follows:

```
erreur (TABLE)
    -id (PRIMARY, AUTO INDENT, INT)
    -id_machine (INT, FOREIGN KEY)
    -type_erreur (VARCHAR[50])
    -description_erreur (VARCHAR[200])
    -date_detection (TIMESTAMP)
    -date (TIMESTAMP)
```

I'm using Xampp to have my server and database in localhost/test.  So it seems the script does receive the GET request, but does not execute.

The thing is, I m still learner in python, and complete neophyte in php, so I don t know where to search in the code.

The final goal is:

```
agent.py --GET--> erreur.php --SQL--> bliss.erreur
```

Since there would be a lot of agents, sending SQL request from the Python script isn't a solution.

Can anyone validate that the Python script works, and/or give me a clue about where did I go wrong in the code?

wget with -O flag:

```
drakasan@debian:~$ wget -O - http://localhost/test/erreur.php?id_machine=1,type_erreur=ping,description_erreur=test,date_detection=1381241491,date=1381241491
--2013-10-08 16:19:31--  http://localhost/test/erreur.php?id_machine=1,type_erreur=ping,description_erreur=test,date_detection=1381241491,date=1381241491
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 826 [text/html]
Saving to: `STDOUT'

 0% [                                                                                                             ] 0           --.-K/s              <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: type_machine in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/erreur.php</b> on line <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: description_erreur in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/erreur.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: date_detection in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/erreur.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: date in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/erreur.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/erreur.php</b> on line <b>11</b><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: nom_machine in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/erreur.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
vous devez renseigner tous les champs
<html>
    <form method='GET' action='#'>
    </form>
</html>
100%[============================================================================================================>] 826         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2013-10-08 16:19:31 (69.1 MB/s) - written to stdout [826/826]
```

Comment: Test the URL with a `wget` from commandline to determine if is the PHP script that fails (like it seems)

Comment: Apparently you have "shortened" the script too much.  I don't see how your code could print the arguments (line 9) then continue to reach the last two lines ("200" and "OK" in outut) without printing the full query (line 12) in between.

Comment: Also look at the response *content* given (i.e. use wget or `print res.read()`).  It's been a while since I saw PHP, but from I read, I don't see any reason why the script would not return `200 OK` status, even if the SQL part failed.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: Well, I ve ran the shortened script to get the output, so I guess it work somehow. If I understand your second comment, the error do come from the php script?

Comment: @DrakaSAN I really don't see how it's possible to get the output you posted from the code you posted.  Can you re-check?  Regarding the errors, I mean that the php script sure did return the 200 OK, but you don't output the *content*, i.e. the strings that you `echo`.  In order to see that, use the `read()` method OR wget, but with `-O -` (dash, big oh, space, dash) ,  like this: `wget -O - http://localhost/...`  The `-O -` makes wget display the content (supposedly one of your French strings plus a set of empty HTML tags) right in the terminal.

Comment: @AloisMahdal: I ve made copy/paste of python script & execution, and edited my post to add the -O flag (and erase the typo)

Comment: You don't get the URI query syntax right. It's ampersand, not comma, e.g.: `?par=value&par1=value2`.  (Note that you will need to quote the URI to pass it to wget.)

Comment: And please read *the Markdown* help.  With each of your edits, it becomes less clear how your code and errors actually looks like.

Comment: I definitely suggest learning to use mysqldb in Python. It's just as easy to use as the php database stuff.

Comment: As a side note, you also got the HTTP protocol wrong. A GET request must be idempotent (=> it must not change the state of the server). You want a POST or PUT request here.

Comment: @Alois: It was indeed the comma instead of & which were causing errors, if you want a accepted answer, go on. I ll read the markdown help right now.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: The only thing the page is capable of is adding a row in a database, which don t have anything like password or private information, but I understand your point

Comment: @DrakaSAN: "password or private information" is irrelevant here. There are good reasons for http verbs ("methods") being defined that way. If you do web programming, understanding the HTTP protocol is not optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from other things, you're not following the HTTP URL syntax correctly.  An example
says it all:

```
http://my.host/some/path?foo=1&bar=2
```

the main point being that arguments are divided by `&`, not `,`.

---

Other tips:

- Read up basics of HTTP.  It's not a complicated protocol and it helps a lot
  if you know where you need to look at.

  (hint: there are three parts: status line, headers and body).
- When debugging, always examine also body of the response as well, not only the
  response status.

  In Python, you can do this by printing output of `response.read()` method.
  Other options are using command line tools like wget or curl with proper
  switches:

  ```
  $ wget -O - 'http://my.host/some/path?foo=1&bar=2'
  ...
  $ curl -v 'http://my.host/some/path?foo=1&bar=2'
  ... 
  $
  ```
- Maybe even better alternative is to use a packet sniffer like Wireshark,
  where you can see the whole request and response.  It's also great habit
  if you want to get protocols into your blood system.

  (hint: In Wireshark, right-click a packet and choose "Follow TCP stream")
- Also as bruno points out, GET should not be used for storing data, you should
  use POST (I think it's stored as `$_POST` in PHP) instead.

  Just as the names suggest: GET means to get, POST means to post.
- Last but not least, your PHP code was unlikely to produce a valid HTML.
  The `<? ... >` part is replaced by anything it prints (echoes), so your
  actual output would be like:

  ```
  vous devez renseigner tous les champs
  <html>
      <form method='GET' action='#'>
      </form>
  </html>
  ```

  which is definitely not a valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an undefined variable warning in PHP, you need to take care of that immediately. In this case, you have `$nom_machine &&`, which, because `$nom_machine` is not defined, is basically equivalent to `if(FALSE &&`. That means the code inside of that `if` will never run.

On the Python side, you should be reading the output and not just the headers. (eg. `print res.read()`). PHP will often display errors *after* the headers have been sent, which means you could have a fatal error or an empty response with a `200` header.